# Mensaje de alerta - HTML - CSS

Tags: javascript, html

¿Se puede personalizar el mensaje de alerta para que en lugar de que me salga el `alert("mensaje que deseemos);` me aparezca el `<input>` correspondiente de un color rojo para denotar que está erróneo el campo?

¿O también se podría centrar el mensaje del `alert();` para que salga en mitad del formulario y asi hacer click, con unos estilos más vistosos?

```js
function validar() {
  var nombre, apellidos, email, dni, telefono, password1, password2;
  var expresion;

  nombre = document.getElementById("nombre").value;
  apellidos = document.getElementById("apellidos").value;
  email = document.getElementById("email").value;
  dni = document.getElementById("dni").value;
  telefono = document.getElementById("telefono").value;
  password1 = document.getElementById("password1").value;
  password2 = document.getElementById("password2").value;

  expresion = /^[_a-z0-9-]+(.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(.[a-z0-9-]+)*(.[a-z]{2,4})$/;

  if (nombre == "" || apellidos == "" || email == "" || dni == "" || telefono == "" || password1 == "" || password2 == "") {
    alert("Todos los campos son obligatorios.");
    return false;
  } else if (nombre.length > 20) {
    alert("El nombre debe tener menos de 21 carácteres.");
    document.getElementById("nombre").focus();
    return false;
  } else if (apellidos.length > 50) {
    alert("Los apellidos superan los 50 carácteres de límite.");
    document.getElementById("apellidos").focus();
    return false;
  } else if (!expresion.test(email)) {
    alert("El formato del email es incorrecto.");
    document.getElementById("email").value = "";
    document.getElementById("email").focus();
    return false;
  } else if (email.length > 50) {
    alert("El email debe tener menos de 51 carácteres.");
    document.getElementById("email").value = "";
    document.getElementById("email").focus();
    return false;
  } else if (dni.length != 9) {
    alert("El DNI debe tener exactamente 9 carácteres.");
    document.getElementById("dni").value = "";
    document.getElementById("dni").focus();
    return false;
  } else if (telefono.length != 9) {
    alert("El teléfono debe tener exactamente 9 carácteres.");
    document.getElementById("telefono").value = "";
    document.getElementById("telefono").focus();
    return false;
  } else if (isNaN(telefono)) {
    alert("El teléfono debe contener únicamente dígitos.");
    document.getElementById("telefono").value = "";
    document.getElementById("telefono").focus();
    return false;
  } else if (password1 != password2) {
    alert("Las contraseñas no coinciden.");
    document.getElementById("password1").value = "";
    document.getElementById("password2").value = "";
    document.getElementById("password1").focus();
    return false;
  }
}
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  background: #204862;
}

h1 {
  margin-top: 100px;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
}

.form-register {
  width: 95%;
  max-width: 500px;
  margin: auto;
  background: white;
  border-radius: 7px;
}

.form-titulo {
  background: green;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: 100;
  font-size: 30px;
  border-top-left-radius: 7px;
  border-top-right-radius: 7px;
  border-bottom: 5px solid red;
}

.contenedor-inputs {
  padding: 2px 20px;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

input {
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  padding: 4px;
  font-size: 12px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

label {
  font-size: 16px;
}

.input-2 {
  width: 48%;
}

.input-1 {
  width: 98%;
}

.registrar {
  background: crimson;
  color: #fff;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 10px 40px;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 12px;
}

.registrar:active {
  transform: scale(1.05);
}

.form-link {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 7px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 14px;
}

.footer {
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 14px;
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 150px;
  height: 40px;
  padding: 5px 0px;
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Formulario de Registro</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="estilos_registrar.css">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="validar.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Formulario de Registro</h1>
  <form name="miformulario" id="miformulario" action="registrar.php" method="POST" class="form-register" onsubmit="return validar();">
    <h2 class="form-titulo">CREA UNA CUENTA</h2>
    <div class="contenedor-inputs">
      <!-- Por cada etiqueta de <input> <label for="id_mismo_que_input">XXXX: </label> -->
      <input type="text" name="nombre" id="nombre" placeholder="Nombre" tabindex="1" class="input-2">
      <input type="text" name="apellidos" id="apellidos" placeholder="Apellidos" tabindex="2" class="input-2">
      <br/>
      <input type="text" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Email" tabindex="3" class="input-1">
      <br/>
      <input type="text" name="dni" id="dni" placeholder="DNI" tabindex="4" class="input-2">
      <input type="text" name="telefono" id="telefono" placeholder="Teléfono" tabindex="5" class="input-2">
      <br/>
      <input type="password" name="password" id="password1" placeholder="Contraseña" tabindex="6" class="input-2">
      <input type="password" name="password" id="password2" placeholder="Repetir contraseña" tabindex="7" class="input-2">
      <br/>
      <input type="submit" value="Registrar" name="registrar" class="registrar" tabindex="8" />
      <?php
     include "Clases/BD.php";
     //Si pulsamos el botón insertar...
     if(isset($_POST["registrar"])){
      $nombre = $_POST["nombre"];
      $apellidos = $_POST["apellidos"];
      $dni = $_POST["dni"];
      $telefono = $_POST["telefono"];
      $email = $_POST["email"];
      $password = $_POST["password"];
      //Llamamos al método "insertarCliente" y le pasamos los parámetros del formulario.
      BD::insertarCliente($email, $nombre, $apellidos, $dni, $telefono, $password);
     }
    ?>
        <p class="form-link">¿Ya tienes una cuenta? <a href="iniciar_sesion.php">Ingresa aquí</a></p>
    </div>
  </form>
  <!--<div class="footer">
   <p>Copyrigth</p>
  </div>-->
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Los estilos del mensaje de alerta no se puede modificar.

Comment: los **alert** no se pueden modificar por medio de css porque no forman parte del DOM, hay una librería llamada [sweet alert](https://github.com/t4t5/sweetalert) con la que puede solucionar el problema, es una emulación de los alert personalizable

Answer (score 0):

Lastimosamente los estilos del alert del navegador no se pueden cambiar de ninguna manera, pero existen librerías muy completas y geniales que ayudan a crear alerts con un diseño muy visual, entre esas librerías te recomiendo [sweetalert](https://limonte.github.io/sweetalert2/), es la que yo uso es muy completa y funcional.

```js
swal ( "Oops" ,  "Something went wrong!" ,  "error" )
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/limonte-sweetalert2/6.11.4/sweetalert2.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/limonte-sweetalert2/6.11.4/sweetalert2.min.css">
```

Answer (score 0):

Recomiendo la librería de alertify para jQuery, a mi parecer es muy sencilla de utilizar y a la vez muy completa, tanto en el manejo de mensajes emergentes y como en prompt.

Ya trae sus propios estilos así que te sera muy útil en el manejo de mensajes de errores.

https://alertifyjs.org

Implementación:

```js
alertify.error("El nombre debe tener menos de 21 carácteres.");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/alertifyjs/alertify.js/v1.0.10/dist/js/alertify.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Otra opción es usar el plugin de JQuery llamado MsgBox y personalizarlo con css.

Te dejo un ejemplo:

```js
$.alert("soy el mapa soy el mapa soy el mapa!");
```

```css
.msgbox-msg {
  color: crimson;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://raw.githack.com/composite/jQuery.MsgBox/master/jquery.msgbox.min.js"></script>
```